# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' in safari browser

Tags: safari, syntax-error, angular5

I tried to run angular webapp(created in angular=5 & using CLI=1.5.0) but it's not working in safari browser ONLY. However its working fine in chrome & mozilla browser.

To resolve this I tried to uncomment import for core-js/es6/object & so on.. from polyfills.ts but still it doesn't work.

ERROR:
vendor.bundle.js:758 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the very same exact problem.

Comment: @Simos.. didn't get the exact solution but for now got the reason as safari version >10 will support angular 5 code with const token!

Comment: For me when i did build --prod it worked, but during development it didnt work. I"m happy as i'm not developing in safari though so not big problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295047/safari-reporting-unexpected-token-const-when-i-open-my-react-app - shows possible source of problem