# Safari reporting "Unexpected token 'const' " when I open my React App

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I have problem with my React App opening in Safari and especially my private routing.Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

I have ordinary rooting function:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dash" component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/filters" component={Filters} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/map" component={Map} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/bookmarks" component={Bookmarks} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/client/:planID/:isLarge" component={Client} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/analyses/:planID/:isLarge"
          component={Analyses}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The problem is with this **PrivateRoute** because when I remove the import and tags it is not displaying the error. Here is my private route file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        sessionStorage.getItem("Token") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

I suspect something in returning is not right for Safari but I do not know what. Also this is working in this way on Chrome, Mozilla, IE and Edge. Only Safari have problems.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the screenshot of issue in Safari:
[image]

Comment: Try this before the return statement; `const token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token")`. Then within the return statement, use the "token" for that login check.

Comment: @MwamiTovi Same issue

Comment: Oh really!! Thought that would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem was arrow function declaration. Safari 5.1 is really bad and for getting well with all browsers it is better to avoid ES6 syntax arrow functions. From this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        sessionStorage.getItem("Token") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
```

I transformed code to this:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={function(props) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem("Token") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
```

Comment: It's great you have gotten a way around this. To achieve browser compatibility, we better avoid arrow functions, right?

Comment: @MwamiTovi Yes, seems the best practice is to avoid ES6 functionalities because not all browsers understands ES6.

Comment: Point noted. Am very serious fan of arrow functions. But now I understand why even in the official React docs "mostly" uses normal functions. Probably to caution us to use arrow functions sparingly:(

Comment: that's why your use a transpiler like Babel so you can write your code in es6 and transform it to es5 for prod.